# How to create a combination of all the numbers after the first digit, in separate lines

Tags: awk

I have a big data with rows like this:

This data is in txt format:

```
0   1,5,6,4
2,23,43,5,6
1   4 5 2 3
5   4 5 6 7
56,65
```

Each line considers being from the first digit and the other series of digits after the space.
I need to take the digit before the space and have a line combination with these digits with all other digits in the same line after the space that separated by a comma.

for example:
I want to create new file and convert this data into 2 columns like this:

```
0 1
0 5
0 6
0 4
0 2
0 23
0 43
0 5
0 6
1 4
1 5
1 2
1 3
5 4
5 5
and so on...
```

I will appreciate any help!
This is an example of 5 lines from the file I need to make this change on.

[image: Example of the input]

Comment: since some lines in your file is also splited into several lines then the last number for example in first line `0   1,5,6,4` is 4 or is that 42 which it break the second digit `2` in the second next line? or is that becasue of Terminal column limit which then the rest of the line is in the next row where it's actually the continution of same previous line?

Comment: Replace `and so on...` in  your expected output with the rest of your expected output. We can't test a potential solution with just input. If there's too much output for you to type then there's too much input, reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

May the `awk` be with you

```
function splitAndPrint(lineId, line, separator) {
    split(line, arr, separator)

    for (v in arr){
        print lineId" "arr[v]
    }
}


{
    if ($0 ~ /^[0-9] /) { # matches the digit before space
        digitBeforeSpace = $1
        sub(/^[0-9] +/, "") # removes that digit
    }
    if($0 ~ /,/){
        # separator is ,
        splitAndPrint(digitBeforeSpace, $0, ",")
    }
    else {
        # separator is space
        splitAndPrint(digitBeforeSpace, $0, " ")
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ($0 ~ /^[0-9] /)` = `if (/^[0-9] /)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ cat input_file
0   1,5,6,4,2,23,43,5,6
1   4,5,2,3
5   4,5,6,7,56,65
```

```
$ sed ':a;s/\([^ ]*\) \+\([^,]*\),/\1 \2\n\1 /;ta' input_file
0 1
0 5
0 6
0 4
0 2
0 23
0 43
0 5
0 6
1 4
1 5
1 2
1 3
5 4
5 5
5 6
5 7
5 56
5 65
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Where in the code did you decide which characters to take for the separating between the first digits and the other after it? Because in my case, I understood it is a TAB space and not a regular space.

Comment: @Dan If it is tab seperated, and you also want tab seperated output, try this `sed ':a;s/\([^\t]*\)\t\([^,]*\),/\1\t\2\n\1\t/;ta' input_file`